# Setting up Open Project email

Tags: openproject

has anyone ever set up their open project email that the program comes with? Open Project is an open source program. I was just curious, lets say I set up my email settings, how do I test it to make sure it works? I am not sure what to be looking for.

Best

Mike

Answer (score 4):

Which version of OpenProject do you use? (I recommend to use the new version 3).

If you are on OpenProject 3, have a look at [`config/configuration.yml`](https://github.com/opf/openproject/blob/dev/config/configuration.yml.example#L45) and [`doc/CONFIGURATION.md`](https://github.com/opf/openproject/blob/dev/doc/CONFIGURATION.md).

There you see a lot of email related options (especially the SMTP options might be useful for you). To enable these options, copy `config/configuration.yml.example` to `config/configuration.yml` and make your changes around line 103:

```
default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
  email_delivery_method: :smtp
  smtp_address: smtp.example.net
  smtp_port: 25
  smtp_domain: example.net
  smtp_authentication: :login
  smtp_user_name: "openproject@example.net"
  smtp_password: "my_openproject_password"
```

(If you choose to provide environment variables instead (as described in CONFIGURATION.md) you don't need to copy the `configuration.yml`)

With these settings, your OpenProject installation should be able to send mails. If you are logged in as an administrator, you should visit the `https://<your OpenProject instance>/settings?tab=notifications` page. There are some useful settings and (at the bottom of the page) a 'send test mail' link.

You might find further help in the OpenProject forums - especially at [this topic](https://www.openproject.org/topics/292).

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting the parameters in the Admin -> Parameters page. I filled out SMTP Server, Port, Username and Password.

Unfortunately it is not working. This is the cmd_string in file `acs-mail-lite-procs.tcl`:

```
smtp::sendmessage ::mime::1 -originator bounce-36813-AE60A926C4ED8A784755AE1362497649C9565989-21457@AS02 -header {From it@sybit.ch} -header {Reply-To it@sybit.ch} -header {To thorsten.niehues@sybit.ch} -servers smtp.office365.com -ports 587 -username thorsten.niehues@sybit.ch -password PASSWORD
```

The error message is:

```
Error: member-notify: Error sending to "thorsten.niehues@sybit.ch": 530: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM
```

**Solution:**

Since the forum of project-open and google is not very helpful I chose to setup our server to work with exchange like on this description: [Configure Postfix to Use Gmail SMTP on Ubuntu](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/) (I think this solution works for most Email servers)

Then I added this line to the end of the `ad_proc -public send` method (also in the `acs-mail-lite-procs.tcl file`):

```
exec /web/projop/poSendEmail.sh $body $subject $to_addr
```

Finally the `poSendEmail.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Call this script with parameter:
# $1 message content
# $2 mail subject
# $3 receipient (to field)
MSG=${1//\"/}
MSG=$(echo $MSG | tr -d '\r')
echo "Sending mail with parameter: $MSG, $2, $3" >> /web/projop/log/all.log
echo "$MSG" | mail -s "$2" -r it@sybit.ch $3
```